# How to Add Image to Telerik DatePicker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc

I am using telerik DatePicker in my MVC3 project like :-

```
  <ul class="floatleft width25">
          <li>
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.AppointmentDate)%>
            <%: Html.Telerik().DatePickerFor(model => model.caseSearchRequest.AppointmentDate).OpenOnFocus(true).ShowButton(true)%>
         </li>
  </ul>
```

Please tell mo how i to add a image for opening calendar for this datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to change the icon which comes with each DatePicker? This can easily be done by just modifying the **sprite.png** file which is tied to each of the provided Telerik skins. Just open up that file (located in the *[install directory]/content/[version number]/[skin name]/*) in your favorite image editor and change the icon around.

If for some reason this icon is not being displayed at all then I believe there are issues related to the CSS files not being sent to the client. I would use the Developer Tools of the browser to check if any issues appear with **sprite.png** not getting downloaded properly.